# Importing torchvision in PyCharm using Anaconda

Tags: python, pytorch, pycharm, anaconda

I installed PyCharm and Anaconda and I tried to import Torchvison for my Python project.

Yet, it raise the following issue

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
```

And I try to run

```
conda install -c pytorch torchvision
```

as suggested here https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/12210 on Anaconda prompt but still PyCharm still warn me no module named PyCharm found.

Comment: Have you activated conda env that is used pycharm while running `conda install -c pytorch torchvision` in anaconda prompt?

Comment: how to do that?